# How can I authenticate users via social account from mobile app using retrofit2?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

I'm trying to connect my website's API and mobile app. I need to authenticate the user with google account but I don't know how to do it.

I created the backend with Django. And I set the endpoint as `rest-auth/google/`. On the restframework's page, it requires Access Token and Code but honestly I don't get how I can test if it actually works using actual google account.
I want to test from mobile app but I don't understand how and what I need to POST.

Anyone could give me tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a ready solution like "django-allauth".

If you want to do authentication yourself you might want to read Google's documentation about the topic:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

In nutshell you create API credentials:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Send a user to a link with specific parameters (api-credentials, scope, redirect link etc). Google client can help you to generate it.

A user will login in his account as he would normally do and will give your app permissions to use his information (or won't). After that he will be redirected to the link you specified with GET request with a code as a parameter (or error).

With help of Google client you can exchange the code on a token and then use that token to get information from his profile.